# R convert regression model fit to a function

Tags: r, regression, lm

I want to quickly extract the fit of a regression model to a function.

So I want to get from:

```
# generate some random data
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 4)
z <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = -8, sd = 3)
y <- 9 * x - 10 * x ^ 2 + 5 * z + 10 + rnorm(n = 100, 0, 30)


df <- data.frame(x,y)
plot(df$x,df$y)

model1 <- lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) + z, data = df)
summary(model1)
```

to a `model_function(x)` that describes the fitted values for me.

Of course I could do this by hand in a way like this:

```
model_function <- function(x, z, model) {
  fit <- coefficients(model)["(Intercept)"] + coefficients(model)["x"]*x + coefficients(model)["I(x^2)"]*x^2 + coefficients(model)["z"]*z
  return(fit)
}

fit <- model_function(df$x,df$z, model1)
```

which I can compare to the actual fitted values and (with some rounding errors) works perfectly.

```
all(round(as.numeric(model1$fitted.values),5) == round(fit,5))
```

But of course this is not a universal solution (e.g. more variables etc.).

So to be clear:
**Is there an easy way to extract the fitted values relationship as a function with the coefficients that were just estimated?**

Note: I know of course about `predict` and the ability to generate fitted values from new data - but I'm really looking for that underlying function. Maybe that's possible through `predict`?

Grateful for any help!

Comment: You can check `predict.lm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an actual function you can do something like this:

```r
get_func <- function(mod) {
  vars <- as.list(attr(mod$terms, "variables"))[-(1:2)]
  funcs <- lapply(vars, function(x) list(quote(`*`), 1, x))
  terms <- mapply(function(x, y) {x[[2]] <- y; as.call(x)}, funcs, mod$coefficients[-1],
         SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  terms <- c(as.numeric(mod$coefficients[1]), terms)
  body <- Reduce(function(a, b) as.call(list(quote(`+`), a, b)), terms)
  vars <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(vars), function(x) NULL), sapply(vars, as.character))
  f <- as.function(c(do.call(alist, vars), body))
  formals(f) <- formals(f)[!grepl("\\(", names(formals(f)))]
  f
}
```

Which allows:

```r
my_func <- get_func(model1)

my_func
#> function (x = NULL, z = NULL) 
#> 48.6991866925322 + 3.31343108778127 * x + -9.77589420188036 * I(x^2) + 5.38229596972984 * z
<environment: 0x00000285a1982b48>
```

and

```r
my_func(x = 1:10, z = 3)
#> [1]   58.38361   32.36936  -13.19668  -78.31451 -162.98413 -267.20553 
#> [7] -390.97872 -534.30371 -697.18048 -879.60903
```

and

```r
 plot(1:10, my_func(x = 1:10, z = 3), type = "b")
```

[image]

At the moment, this would not work with interaction terms, etc, but should work for most simple linear models

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Any of these give the fitted values:

```
fitted(model1)

predict(model1)

model.matrix(model1) %*% coef(model1)

y - resid(model1)

X <- model.matrix(model1); X %*% qr.solve(X, y)

X <- cbind(1, x, x^2, z); X %*% qr.solve(X, y)
```

Any of these give the predicted values for any particular x and z:

```
cbind(1, x, x^2, z) %*% coef(model1)

predict(model1, list(x = x, z = z))
```